# stan error "undefined values" while fitting logistic model

Tags: stan

New stan user here. This particular model (basically a mixed effects logistic regression) will run sometimes, but will often get errors "The following variables have undefined values:  log_lik[182]" etc. It is always a problem with the "dev" or "log_lik" values. The index it gets caught on is sometimes at the transition between areas, but also in random places in some runs.

stan model:

```
data{
    int nObs;
    int S[nObs];
    int<lower=0> n[nObs];
    real Area2[nObs];
    real Area3[nObs];
    real Julian_Day[nObs];
    int Year[nObs];
    int nYears;
}

parameters{
    real intercept_raw;
    real beta_Area2_raw;
    real beta_Area3_raw;
    real gamm_raw;
    real gamm_raw_Area2;
    real gamm_raw_Area3;
    real vary_Year[nYears];
    real<lower=0> sigma_Year;
}

transformed parameters {
    real intercept;
    real beta_Area2;
    real beta_Area3;
    real gamm;
    real gamm_Area2;
    real gamm_Area3;
    intercept <- intercept_raw*20;
    beta_Area2 <- beta_Area2_raw*5;
    beta_Area3 <- beta_Area3_raw*5;
    gamm <- gamm_raw*5;
    gamm_Area2 <- gamm_raw_Area2*5;
    gamm_Area3 <- gamm_raw_Area3*5;
}

model{
    real vary[nObs];
    real y[nObs];
    // Priors
    intercept_raw ~ normal(0,1);
    beta_Area2_raw ~ normal( 0 , 1 );
    beta_Area3_raw ~ normal( 0 , 1 );
    gamm_raw ~ normal( 0 , 1 );
    gamm_raw_Area2 ~ normal( 0 , 1 );
    gamm_raw_Area3 ~ normal( 0 , 1 );
    sigma_Year ~ cauchy( 0 , 5 );
    // random effect
    for ( j in 1:nYears ) vary_Year[j] ~ normal( 0 , sigma_Year );
    // Fixed effects
    for ( i in 1:nObs ) {
        vary[i] <- vary_Year[Year[i]];
        y[i] <- vary[i] + intercept
                + beta_Area2 * Area2[i]
                + beta_Area3 * Area3[i]
                + gamm * Julian_Day[i]
                + gamm_Area2 * Area2[i] * Julian_Day[i]
                + gamm_Area3 * Area3[i] * Julian_Day[i];
    }
     S ~ binomial_logit( n, y );
}

generated quantities{
  real y_pred[nObs];
  real dev;
  real y[nObs];
  real vary[nObs];
  vector[nObs] log_lik;
  dev <- 0;
    for ( i in 1:nObs ) {
       vary[i] <- vary_Year[Year[i]];
       y[i] <- vary[i] + intercept
                + beta_Area2 * Area2[i]
                + beta_Area3 * Area3[i]
                + gamm * Julian_Day[i]
                + gamm_Area2 * Area2[i] * Julian_Day[i]
                + gamm_Area3 * Area3[i] * Julian_Day[i];
        log_lik[i] <- binomial_log( S[i] , n[i] , inv_logit(y[i]));       
        dev <- dev + (-2) * log_lik[i];
        y_pred[i] <- binomial_rng(100, inv_logit(y[i]) );
    }
}
```

The data looks like this (dataframe "SDF"):

```
 Year Area.ID DayIndex S n Area1 Area2 Area3
1    1       1       19 1 1     1     0     0
2    1       1       22 0 2     1     0     0
3    1       1       23 2 5     1     0     0
4    1       1       24 1 3     1     0     0
5    1       1       26 3 3     1     0     0
6    1       1       28 1 3     1     0     0
```

and these calls are used in R:

```
Dlist <- list ("nObs"=dim(SDF)[1], "S"=SDF$S,  "n"=SDF$n,   
  "Area2"= SDF$Area2,"Area3"= SDF$Area3,  "Julian_Day"=SDF$DayIndex,    
   "Year"=SDF$Year,"nYears"=length(unique(SDF$Year)))

# Fit intercept model using stan
fit_ints <- stan(file='STAN/Logistic_Diff_Slope_SN.stan',data = Dlist, iter=5000, chains=3)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error message occurs when some generated quantity evaluates to `NaN`, usually due to numerical underflow or overflow.

In your case, you can probably avoid it by using the more numerically stable `binomial_logit_log` function rather than the `binomial_log` function (for the same reasons you are using `binomial_logit` in the `model` block rather than `binomial`). In other words, it should be

`log_lik[i] <- binomial_logit_log( S[i] , n[i] , y[i]);`

rather than

`log_lik[i] <- binomial_log( S[i] , n[i] , inv_logit(y[i]));`

In addition, when drawing from the posterior predictive distribution, you could do something like

`p <- inv_logit(y[i]);
if (is_nan(p)) y_pred[i] <- y[i] > 0;
else if (p >= 1) y_pred[i] <- 1;
else if (p <= 0) y_pred[i] <- 0;
else y_pred[i] <- binomial_rng(100, inv_logit(y[i]));`

Unfortunately, there is no `binomial_logit_rng` function in Stan at the moment.